# Spring MVC session attribute is lost after uploading a large file

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, file-upload, exception

One of the functionalities of my Spring MVC application is uploading large files (about 500MB) which should be processed later.

The controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("/folderManagement/")
@Controller("FolderFormController")
@SessionAttributes({ "tabTitle", "selectedFolder" })
public class FolderFormController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = FOLDER_FORM)
    protected ModelAndView showFolderManager(@RequestParam(value = "selectedFolderId", required = false) Long selectedFolderId,
            @RequestParam(value = "selectedDocId", required = false) Long selectedDocId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // Generates the page attributes
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName(FOLDER_FORM_VIEW);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = UPLOAD_FILES, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView postUploadFile(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("uploadItem") UploadItem upitem, @ModelAttribute("selectedFolder") FolderForm root, BindingResult result,
            SessionStatus status, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        // Process upitem
        Log.debug("INIT");
    }

}
```

UploadItem is an object which has a CommonsMultipartFile (org.springframework.web.multipart.commons) inside.

It usually works ok. No matter the size of the file (even 800MB), nor the time it takes to process. However, there are some times that the user is getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute 'selectedFolder'
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptorFilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:448)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:403)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This exception is catched by this method:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class})
public ModelAndView handleExceptionArray(Exception ex) {
    Log.error("Recogida excepcion " + ex.getClass().getSimpleName(), ex);
    String errorMessage = "Internal error";
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    // modelAndView.setViewName("error/error");
    modelAndView.addObject("name", "");
    modelAndView.addObject("exception", errorMessage);

    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:" + FolderFormController.getRedirectUrl());
    saveError(modelAndView, errorMessage);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Besides, the Log "INIT" isn't printed, so it's not entering into the controller method.

What is happenning? And, more important, how could I avoid this? Any ideas?

**Update: Causes**

Well, it seems the cause is the user session expiration. Tomcat has a expiration time of 30 minutes. If the upload takes more than that, then it doesn't reach my controller. Is there any way to avoid this loss of the session?

Comment: Since this issue is intermittent and there is a HttpSessionRequiredException, a session expiry is a suspect (assuming SessionStatus.setComplete() has not been called). One solution to avoid this is to persist selectedFolder on the client side (using hidden fields) and to post those fields when uploading the file.

Comment: selectedFolder is posted to postUploadFile from a form that has this attribute. Also, how could a session be expired while uploading a file? The communication is not stopped, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You already found out it must be a problem with session timeout, good. If no new requests hit the particular session after the upload was started it's considered "no activity" which is not correct in your case.

There are several ways to tackle this:

**web.xml**

Increase the timeout in `web.xml`, the default in Tomcat is 30' (i.e. if not specified in `web.xml`).

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>45</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

However, this may not be desirable because as a rule of thumb the timeout should be "as low as possible" - whatever that means. We usually use 5'.

**Alter session**

You may set the general session timeout to 5' but increase it once the upload starts using `HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval`:

> Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the
>   servlet container will invalidate this session. A negative time
>   indicates the session should never timeout.

However, if your controller isn't even called this would have to be done in before Spring. Best candidate is a `ServletFilter`.

**AJAX**

Start a heart-beat request from the client just after the upload was submitted. Then repeat the heart-beat in a loop. If the session timeout is 5' you could use a heart-beat interval of 4'.